# How to store interactive dom values on a server with javascript and not PHP

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb

I wrote an "front end" javascript application that has DOM events in the form of JQuery sliders. I would like to store the user entered values of the sliders on a server.So in short a user would move the sliders, click a button and the slider values would be saved on the server.

Now I know the way to do this with PHP is to have the save button launch a php script that would save the information as tables in a MYSQL database for later retrieval.

However, I would like to do it all in Javascript.

I have read a bit about Node.js and Mongo DB and have a vague idea that it's possible, but I'm not clear.  I've tried to find AJAX-ish code examples that launch Javascript (or hook to node.js or Mongo DB????) in a way that seems similar to conventional usage of PHP/MYSQL but I am having trouble weeding through the clutter.

Is this possible and what technologies are available to make it happen?

Comment: Look at [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) in conjunction with Node.js. You can use MongoDB with Node.js or you can use [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) to store the data. For what you are doing this should work very well.

Comment: So with Node.js/MYSQL I assume that there is a list of commands somewhere that allows me to create tables, connect to the DB etc just like PHP.... all from an html or javascript page? I'm curious about how security works if so, sorry now I'm going off topic. Thanks

Comment: You should also take a look on backbone.js there is a ton of material and howtos out there.: http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/creating-a-rest-api-using-node-js-express-and-mongodb/ or http://backbonetutorials.com/nodejs-restify-mongodb-mongoose/ Using JS in conjunction with MongoDB is kind of a natural fit, since the MongoDB console is using js aswell.

Comment: I started reading a "Sams Teach Yourself" book on node.js and it has a section that teaches the Express framework. It seems like this is the right path for me to go at the moment. I'll eventually look into backbone.js